# Running node on port 80 and apache http on port 81

Tags: php, node.js, apache, google-compute-engine

I am running in Google Compute Engine Node on port 80 and Apache httpd on port 81. But when I try to visit port 81 by the url, which is the IP Address, XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:81, the browser redirects the request to 80 which is the node app. How can I make it work?

ports.conf

```
Listen 81
```

sites-enabled/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
   ....
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I missing? Thank you.

When I deploy the Node app, I have run the following command:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
```

netstat -l

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address        State      
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:81              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssh             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:3000               [::]:*                  LISTEN     
udp        0      0 instance.c:ntp 0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 localhost:ntp           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ntp             0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:bootpc          0.0.0.0:*                          
udp6       0      0 localhost:ntp           [::]:*                             
udp6       0      0 [::]:ntp                [::]:*                             
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     8972     /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12342    /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9021     /run/systemd/fsck.progress
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     27705    /home/myuser/.forever/sock/worker.1508373192880gMA.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10413    /run/acpid.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8907     /run/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8928     /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10225    /run/uuidd/request
```

Comment: Sure the site is not issuing a redirect?

Comment: @nilobarp Thanks for response. I think I haven't done any redirect.

Comment: @CheungBrian You have somewhere, no doubt.  And, it isn't possible from what you've shown us to determine where.

Comment: @CheungBrian use a `devtool network console` to see what is happening. There must be a redirect somewhere.

Comment: @nilobarp I think there must be redirect but I think I haven't issued it. I have updated my problem. Thank you.